# level sets of an Hamiltonian

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider an hamiltonian system

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} = \dot{x}$$
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = -\dot{p}$$

what is the dynamical significance of the level sets of the Hamiltonian $H(x,p) = h$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of it is that $H(x,p)$ is constant:
$$ \dfrac{dH}{dt} = \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p} \dot{p} + \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x} \dot{x} = 0$$
  Thus the trajectories of the system go along these level curves.

EDIT: For example, consider the harmonic oscillator which has $H(x,p) = x^2 + p^2$.  The general solution of the system
$$  \dot{x} = 2 p,\ \dot{p} = - 2 x $$
 can be written as $x = r \sin(2(t - t_0))$, $p = r \cos(2(t - t_0))$
which moves around the circle $H(x,p) = x^2 + p^2 = r^2$.

[image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate a small graphical example for answer completeness? a simple harmonic oscillator will do

Comment: please also clarify what do you mean by "go along these level curves"